# can i use DEBUG_NEW on managed code?

Tags: c++-cli, c#-2.0

can i use:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif
```

in managed code? 

like c# or managed c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work in C++/CLI just as well as it does in standard C++, which is to say, it's officially not allowed to redefine keyword such as `new`, but most compilers will let you do it.

With `__FILE__` there is no problem, although you probably want to store it in a managed string, if you want to use it from managed code.